# Comment re-edit time-out is too short.. and Is there a limit on deleting my comments?

Tags: support, comments, editing

I'd like to know how long a comment I've written is "available" to be re-edited...
Either I'm too slow, or its too fast...

Also, what limits are there on deleting a comment? ...(which I couldn't re-edit because it timed out on me.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a five minute editing window.  (Same as for editing questions and answers without showing as a new edit.)

There are no limits on deleting your own comments.

I know there should be a better SO.meta post about it, but I did find [Please ditch the five-minute window on comment editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/please-ditch-the-five-minute-window-on-comment-editing).

Comment: Thanks.... and it's an interesitng "discussion" in that SO meta post ;)