# Why limit the number of times I can edit a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment re-edit time-out is too short.. and Is there a limit on deleting my comments?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/658/comment-re-edit-time-out-is-too-short-and-is-there-a-limit-on-deleting-my-comm)

I was surprised of this feature. What is it useful for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not limited by edit count, but by [time](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/658/comment-re-edit-time-out-is-too-short-and-is-there-a-limit-on-deleting-my-comme/659#659).